# C# VSTO Excel 2007 - disable hide/unhide button

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I am working on a Excel VSTO 2007 application. I was wondering if there is a way I could disable the `Hide` and `Unhide` buttons present in Excel's <kbd>View</kbd> tab.

[image: www.i.stack.imgur.com/vLfW5.png]

**edit:** I am looking for a way to do it programatically using **c# Code**. The old vba might be useful. I have searched a lot and couldn't find any particular solution.

Comment: you can try setting up a button with matching appearance and ID in your ribbon, not sure if it'll work; Here's the list: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=6627

Comment: Cant really believe it!!! didn't you guys se c#, VSTO tags? And i really don't have any code to show here.

Comment: @Closers: This question is not Off-Topic.  Excel *programming* questions have long been established as *On-Topic* for SO.

Comment: Thanks @RBarryYoung: Appreciate that(y)

Answer (score 2):

I use something like the below to disable the sheet deletion button, perhaps there's something similar for what you want:

```
Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Worksheet.Worksheet excelShtBase;
excelShtBase.Application.CommandBars["Ply"].Controls["&Delete"].Enabled = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can disable the built-in controls in Excel 2007 and onwards, unless you create your own ribbon bar controls with Ribbon XML.

There're lots of examples or tutorials on MSDN, and here's one for you ([Display and Hide Tabs, Groups, and Controls on the Microsoft Office Ribbon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633442%28office.11%29.aspx#odc_office2007_DisplayHideRibbonControls_UsinggetVisibleAttributeBuiltinTabs)).

Comment: This was my last option. Thanks.